# How do i install firebase analytics in my codenameone android app?

Tags: codenameone

I have an android app using google analytics built with codenameone  already  but now i want to move to firebase for my android app analytics how do i carry out the integration.

Answer (score 1):

We currently don't support firebase analytics. There was some discussion in the forums about adding firebase support which isn't hard. Once you do that you can invoke the relevant API's for analytics. This is something that might change in the future but we don't have immediate plans for that.